# I am trying to upload the image but the issue is with the field image of class Contact

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

here is the error I am getting when I submit the add/contact.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='contact'. Error count: 1
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'contact' on field 'image': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@234005aa]; codes [typeMismatch.contact.image,typeMismatch.image,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [contact.image,image]; arguments []; default message [image]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'image'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'image': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

The controller ....

`````
@PostMapping("/process-contact")
    public String processContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact,
            @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file,
            Principal principal,
            HttpSession session) {
        
        try {
            String name = principal.getName();
            User user = this.userRepository.getUserByUserName(name);
            
            //processing and uploading file
            if(file.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Empty file");
                contact.setImage("man.jpg");
            }
            else {
                contact.setImage(file.getOriginalFilename());
                
                File saveFile = new ClassPathResource("static/image").getFile();
                
                Path path = Paths.get(saveFile.getAbsolutePath()+File.pathSeparator+file.getOriginalFilename());
                
                Files.copy(file.getInputStream(),path,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );
                
                System.out.println("Image is uploaded");
            }
            
            //important...
            contact.setUser(user);
            user.getContacts().add(contact);
            //......
            this.userRepository.save(user);
            
            
            System.out.println("DATA : "+contact);
            System.out.println("Contact Added to Database");
            
            //message success....
            session.setAttribute("message", new Message("Your Contact is Added !! Add More..", "success"));
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            //message error..
            session.setAttribute("message", new Message("Soemthing Went Wrong !! Try Again...", "danger"));

        }
        
        return "normal/add_contact_form";
    }
````

the add contact form html file...
<form action="#"
                                th:object="${contact}"
                                enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                method="post"
                                th:action="@{/userr/process-contact}"
                                class="mt-2"
                            >
                            
                            
                            <!-- Contact Description  -->
                            
                            <div class="form-group mt-3 ms-5">
                            
                                <textarea name="description" id="mytextarea" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Contact Description"></textarea>
                            
                            </div>
                            
                            <!-- Contact Image -->
                            
                            <div class="custom-file mt-3">
                            
                                <input type="file" name="image">
                            
                            </div>



enter image description here


[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMhP1.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/emBS0.png



the contact.java file is below

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT")
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int cId;
    private String name;
    private String secondName;
    private String work;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String image;
    @Column(length = 1000)
    private String description;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
`````

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Plese read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and with that knowledge rewrite your question. For starters post code as code not as (links) to images and properly format stacktraces. Your current question is quite unreadable and requires clicking to get a full overview.

Comment: I have updadted it, please look into this

Comment: You are uploading an image, and that input element is named `image`. Your `Contract` also has a property named `image` of type `String`. Spring will try to bind that field `image` (which is a `MultipartFile`) which fails because it is a `String`. Either rename the input element to something else `imageFile` for instance or rename the property to something else `imageFilename`. So no binding will occur.

Comment: Yes, that's worked but now when I tried to retrive the image from database, its shows not found    <img src="" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;"
      class="my_profile_picture" th:src="@{'/image/'+${contact.image}}"
      alt="DP" />

Comment: The image isn't in the database it is on the filesystem, at least that is where you are saving it. So you have to construct the name again to download it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your fieldName as suggested in the comment section.
2. currently, you are saving your image in the system. To get it, you must read it from the system again. Another thing, while calling the `file.getOriginalFileName()` method, be careful with the client provided name, better if you set your own. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992498/spring-boot-multipartfile-upload-getoriginalfilename-different-depending-on-brow)
3. If you want to store your image in database, change your `image` String field with `@Lob(type = LobType.BLOB) private byte[] your_fieldName;`. Set th file content here before saving it to database. Then you can directly get image-data along with other fields